# The name does not exist in the namespace in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Creating a WPF application, using VS2017. I have an enum like:

```
namespace Sample.Common
{
    public enum SmPageTypes
    {
        Type1 = 0,
        Type2 = 1
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use it in xaml form, but get an error:

> The name "SmPageTypes" does not exist in the namespace "clr-Sample.Common;assembly=Sample".

Here is xaml code
adding namespace:

```
xmlns:CommonAlias="clr-namespace:Sample.Common;assembly=Sample"
```

and add enum as resource:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="dataFromEnum" MethodName="GetValues"
                        ObjectType="{x:Type System:Enum}">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <x:Type TypeName="CommonAlias:SmPageTypes" />
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
</Window.Resources>
```

I've added the project, containing this enum, tried to clean, restart Visual Studio, rebuild solution with administrator rights, changed platform target and configuration, it did not help. What else can I do?

Comment: Assuming you have that enum in the common place and you are adding refernce to that common project, can you try something like something this TypeName="{x:Static CommonAlias:SmPageTypes}"

Comment: @AlexK: Is the enum defined in WPF application project or in a class library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem. The reason was that assembly name should be Sample.Common, not Sample.

Answer (score 1):

If the enum and the XAML are in different projects, the project containing the XAML must have a reference to the one containing the enum.

Right-click the XAML project, select Add reference, and add a reference to your enum project.

Answer (score 0):

In VS, right click on your Solution -> Properties -> Configuration Properties

A new dialog is opened, try to change the project configurations from Debug to Release or vice versa.

After that, re-build your solution. It can solve your problem